# document.querySelectorAll didn't get call from generated html element

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6, dom-events

I'm displaying list of div element that generated from .html function whenever users click a button. The code look like below

**array**

```
const obj = [{"id":"1","section":"delivery","label":"Self-Pick up"},{"id":"2","section":"delivery","label":"Delivery"}]
```

**javascript**

```
createFilterBubblesTemplate = (obj) => {
  let bubbles = ''
  obj.forEach(e => {
    bubbles += `<div class="filter-btn">
    <span>${e.label}</span>
    <span class="icon-xmark" id="bubbles-close" data-filter-id="${e.id}" data-filter-section="${e.section}"></span>
    </div>`
  })
  $("#filtered-items").html(bubbles);
}
```

**html element after generated by *createFilterBubblesTemplate* function**

```
<div class="filter-items" id="filtered-items">
    <div class="filter-btn">
    <span>Self-Pick up</span>
    <span class="icon-xmark" id="bubbles-close" data-filter-id="1" data-filter-section="delivery"></span>
    </div><div class="filter-btn">
    <span>Delivery</span>
    <span class="icon-xmark" id="bubbles-close" data-filter-id="2" data-filter-section="delivery"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I tried to  attach click eventlistener on span with class="icon-xmark", its seems not working. Need help to solve this issue

```
document.querySelectorAll('.icon-xmark').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    console.log(event)
  })
})
```

Comment: Maybe add the onclick when you create the elements

Comment: Multiple `id="bubbles-close"` you cannot have identical ids they must be unique.

Comment: @zer00ne While you are absolutely correct it should not affect the code shown

Comment: @zer00ne removing the id didn't resolve the issue

Comment: No, hence a comment not an answer.

Comment: Cannot form a solid answer since there's two patches of JS/jQ and `document.querySelectorAll('.icon-xmark')` is a "static" NodeList so...depends. If you are using jQuery why would you not use `.on()` method instead?

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed by using answer from Arm144. Attaching onclick attribute into the span

```
createFilterBubblesTemplate = async (obj) => {
  let bubbles = ''
  obj.forEach(e => {
    bubbles += `<div class="filter-btn">
    <span>${e.label}</span>
    <span class="icon-xmark" onclick="closeFiltersBubbles(${e.id},'${e.section}')" data-filter-id="${e.id}" data-filter-section="${e.section}"></span>
    </div>`
  })
  $("#filtered-items").html(bubbles);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are attach the event BEFORE you added the element to the DOM.
Try to delegate the event

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const target = event.target;
  if (target.classList.contains('icon-xmark')) {
    console.log(event);
  }
});
```

but it's better to use the date attribute

```
<span class="icon-xmark" data-close id="bubbles-close" data-filter-id="2" data-filter-section="delivery"></span>
  ...
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const target = event.target;
  if ('close' in target.dataset) {
    console.log(event);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The spans you assign the click handler to are empty, thus they are rendered with 0 width and you cannot click them.

The following corrects this by adding content (non-breaking spaces).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"   content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="expires"        content="0">
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control"  content="private">
        <meta http-equiv="pragma"         content="no-cache">
        <title>SO - Bitmap (svg)</title>
        <!--
        -->
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color:   #eee;
            }
            
            .icon-xmark {
                background-color:   lime;
                cursor:             pointer;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            const obj = [{"id":"1","section":"delivery","label":"Self-Pick up"},{"id":"2","section":"delivery","label":"Delivery"}];
            
            let createFilterBubblesTemplate = (obj) => {
              let bubbles = '';
              obj.forEach(e => {
                bubbles += `<div class="filter-btn">
                <span>${e.label}</span>
                <span class="icon-xmark" id="bubbles-close" data-filter-id="${e.id}" data-filter-section="${e.section}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                </div>`;
              });
              document.querySelector("#filtered-items").innerHTML = bubbles;
            }; //   createFilterBubblesTemplate
                              
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                setTimeout ( () => {
                        createFilterBubblesTemplate(obj);
                        setTimeout ( () => {
                                document.querySelectorAll('.icon-xmark').forEach(item => {
                                    item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                                        console.log('Here we go...');
                                    });
                                });
                            } 
                          , 1000
                        );
                    }
                  , 1000
                );
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="filter-items" id="filtered-items"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate click event with jQuery method [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/). Bind the click event to a static element (an element that's been there since the page loaded, like `#filtered-items`) and then delegate the click event to the `.icon-xmark` the user clicked (`$(this)`). This indirect way of event handling is called [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation). This is necessary since you cannot bind event handlers to dynamically added elements.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
const obj = [{
  "id": "1",
  "section": "delivery",
  "label": "Self-Pick up"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "section": "delivery",
  "label": "Delivery"
}]

/*
A proper arrow function should begin with a const or let
`.html()` method is like `.innerHTML` in that it it's destructive
Use `.append()`
*/
const createFilterBubblesTemplate = (obj) => {
  obj.forEach(e => {
    let html =`<div class="filter-btn">
    <span>${e.label}</span>
    <span class="icon-xmark" data-filter-id="${e.id}" data-filter-section="${e.section}"></span>
    </div>`;
    $("#filtered-items").append(html);
  });
}

/*
Delegate click events to each ".icon-xmark" by binding the click event to
the parent tag "#filtered-items"
Note the second parameter ".icon-xmark" -- that designates "this" as ".icon-xmark"
console.log(event) does nothing
*/
$("#filtered-items").on('click', ".icon-xmark", function(e) {
  const x = $(this).data('filter-id');
  console.log(x);
});

createFilterBubblesTemplate(obj);
```

```css
.icon-xmark {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: 1px red dashed
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-items" id="filtered-items"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```